# Eclipse Juno (both 4.2.2 and 4.2.1) does not run on Mac Sierra (10.12)

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-juno, macos-sierra

I've tried editing the file `eclipse.ini` and set the vm with the paths of the various JDKs installed but still it does not open on Mac Sierra (10.12).
I've tried the following JDKs:

> 1.6.0.jdk 
> jdk1.7.0_79.jdk 
> jdk1.8.0_20.jdk

Comment: Why not use the current release, Neon, which is 4 years newer? Which Juno download is it? What happens instead of opening? How are you trying to open it?

Comment: @nitind, unfortunately I need this specific version. Eclipse 4.2.2. It crash immediately. Double click on the launch file.

Comment: Update 20 of Java 8 is old, the current update is 101. Try using current versions of the JDKs

Comment: @greg-449, yes, I already tried with jdk 8 update 101.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeeded to launch eclipse juno on Mac Sierra (10.12) simply by double-clicking the executable inside the following path: `/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse`

Comment: This sounds like the [problem I had with Audacity](http://forward-in-code.blogspot.co.uk/2016/08/audacity-212-and-el-capitan.html) - see also comments [on this post](http://forward-in-code.blogspot.co.uk/2016/07/the-application-is-damaged-and-cant-be.html).